# Sample application for generating energy from Piezeo Electric Crystal.?

Tags: piezoelectricity

I am working on a project where I need to prove that Piezeo electric crystal can help us to generate electricity and can be applicable on streets.My question is that where can I find suitable transcendence or Piezeo electric energy generating unit.I would also like to know if such things are already implemented. I am also seeking for proper elements to make this things happen. Since I live in India the local markets are really poor having such sophisticated equipment. I would also like to know if I could order the parts online. All suggestions are welcomed.Thanks

Comment: What is your target application? How much power or energy or voltage do you need? Piezo is probably not the best way to make electricity in most situations. It has it's uses but usually other means are better. Search for "windbelt" as one possibility - this type of system can be vibration powered.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, existance proof of such devices are already available on the street.

Many ignitors work on the priciple of applying a mechanical shock to a piezo crystal, which then produces a high enough voltage to cause a spark.  Look at things like barbecue ignitors.

There are also butane lighters with a long (6 inch maybe) stock.  These aren't for cigarettes, but for lighting fires.  They typically have a gun-like trigger.  When squeezed it opens a valve for the butane to flow, and also activates a mechanical mechanism that slaps a piezo crystal.  The high voltage is transferred by wire to the tip where it causes a spark and ignites the butane.

There are other methods used in these types of ignitors so you have to look carefully, but the piezo method is actually quite common nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

If you google for "energy harvest piezo" you get quite a few options for purchasing online.
Here are a couple of results picked at random:

[STEMinc](http://www.steminc.com/SAMPLES_INT.asp?PZ_TYPE=PIEZO%20PLATE), [piezo.com](http://www.piezo.com/prodproto4EHkit.html)

A picture of one of STEMincs products:

[image: piezo harvest]

You could probably also start experiment with a few of the cheap piezo buzzers found in many different products. Here's an [example](http://compare.ebay.co.uk/like/120774782273?var=lv&ltyp=AllFixedPriceItemTypes&var=sbar&adtype=pla) on eBay.

[image: piezo transducer]